# How to display Razor helper code that is inside a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

We are trying to build a form dynamically using code that is stored in the database.  Depending upon what controls we want for a particular form, we put them in a List and pass them to our view.

Inside the view we run through the list outputing the code for each; however, when I do the following

```
foreach(var control in Model.ParameterControls)
{
     @control.code
}
```

I just get the code output in "" which prints the code itself to screen instead of rendering the control.  How do I take a control such as @Html.Textbox("title") or @Html.DevExpress().TextBox("Title") and get it to render from a variable?

***Edit***

ParameterControls is defined as follows

```
    List<ControlModel> ParameterControls
```

Where ControlModel is:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ControlName { get; set; }
    public ParameterType Type { get; set; }
    /* additional irrelevant properties removed */
```

And ParameterType is:

```
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }
```

TypeCode is defined as the control (ie)

```
     @Html.DevExpress().TextBox("Test").GetHtml()
```

Comment: Are you saing that the `code` variable contains a string like `@Html.Textbox("title")` and you want razor to parse _that_ as well?

Comment: That throws an error.  "Only assignment, call, increment,decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var control in Model.ParameterControls)
{
    <text>@control.code</text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I take a control such as @Html.Textbox("title") or
>   @Html.DevExpress().TextBox("Title") and get it to render from a
>   variable?

If you want to Parse Razor String in a varialbe to browser displayable Html and finally display it on a view, then use [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

Sample Code of Razor Engine parsing -

```
  Razor.SetTemplateBase(typeof(HtmlTemplateBase<>));

  string template = 
  @"<html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello @Model.Name</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
      </body>
    </html>";

  var model = new PageModel { Name = "World", Email = "someone@somewhere.com" };
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

Comment: So I would put this in the view and then do a @result ?